# Macro not dividing as it should - part 2

Tags: excel, vba

I posted a question on the Stack site to help with some code because it’s not working exactly the way I want it to. A person kindly responded with the advice, below, but I don’t know what changes are to be made in my code because I don’t understand the suggested change. I was wondering if someone could assist me in changing my code so I can use that change. If need be I can post the entire code if that would help. PS. before anyone responds with why didn’t you just ask the person who gave the suggestion: I did.

Advice: Fix so that trailing right paren is moved 4 pos to the left.

```
Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-"))) - 1
```

I have a macro that works but only when dividing up to 19.00. When 20.00 or higher is the number to be divided it divides to only 10.00 and that’s it.  What it’s suppose to do is divide any number up to 12.00 into 10 cells and any number over 12.00 it’s suppose to write the excess amount to the first number in the found pair. I've copied my Excel sheet. the number to divide is in cell D30 (20.00).

```
Sub DIVIDE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim pair As Variant, accumulator As Variant
Dim findFifteen As Double
Dim remainder As Long, found As Long

found = 1

For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
If Right(pair, 2) = 15 Then
    If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
        findFifteen = pair.Offset(0, 2) / 10
        remainder = 0
    Else
        findFifteen = 1
        remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 10
    End If

    For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
        If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-")   - 1)) Then
            accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
        End If
        accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + findFifteen
    Next accumulator
    End If
Next pair

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Excel sheet:

[image: EXCEL SHEET]

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the issue as well as the issue that are facing. Right now this question reads like: "I went to my mechanic for a problem I was having with a custom car that I built and he suggested that I wrench the 2nd 02 box that I installed after the last repair I performed... what does that mean?" It's unanswerable in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the middle out shows me:

```
pair = "400-bar"
Debug.Print InStr(pair, "-")
Debug.Print Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-"))
Debug.Print Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-"))) - 1
```

resulting in

> 4
>   400-
>   399

So what I think your helper was saying was move the right most parameter (-1) inside the the Left function parenthesis.

```
Debug.Print Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1))
```

resulting in

> 400

Comment: I was asked to supply the whole code but while I was doing that you did your response and thanks so much.  Is this the code you want me to try?                              If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Debug.Print Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-")   - 1)) Then

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried the line  "If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Debug.Print Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then"  but it doesn't work. I don't think this is how you wanted the line to appear and that's where I'm having all my problem with this code. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It was a stab in the dark, @NancySkyes. Now that you've added more information I'll need to have a proper read to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jason, a quick note to say that I resolved it. Thank-you for your help.